# Is there a way to query for Google Calendar Events that have a specific colorId?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

```
 myEvents = await calendar.events.list({
            calendarId: GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID,
            privateExtendedProperty: 'colorId=9',
            maxResults: 100,
            singleEvents: true,
            orderBy: 'startTime',
        })
```

This is what I'm doing, but I get zero results, although there are definitely events of this color on the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the official document of `privateExtendedProperty`, it said as follows. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)

  > Extended properties constraint specified as propertyName=value. Matches only private properties. This parameter might be repeated multiple times to return events that match all given constraints.

  - In this case, it seems that the events cannot be directly searched by the event color. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to retrieve the events by the event color, how about the following patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

If you want to use `privateExtendedProperty`, please add `extendedProperties` to the event. The sample script for Node.js is as follows.

```js
const res = await calendar.events.patch({
  calendarId: "###",
  eventId: "###",
  resource: { extendedProperties: { private: { colorId: "9" } } },
});
```

By this, the event can be retrieved by your showing script.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, first, all events are retrieved. And then, the events are retrieved by `colorId`.

```js
const res = await calendar.events.list({ calendarId, maxResults: 2500 });
const events = res.data.items.filter(({ colorId }) => colorId == 9);
console.log(events);
```

- This is a simple sample script. So, if the number of your events is more than 2500, please retrieve all events using `pageToken`.

#### Reference:

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)